# Why does chrome in docker with python-selenium not download a file?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, docker

I have been trying to use docker, python-selenium and chrome to create a GUI test. However, I have a problem with downloading a file at the end of the test case (which is required - I have to verify its contents).

I am preparing the chrome webdriver as follows:

```
    prefs = {
        "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
        "download.prompt_for_download": "false",
        "download.default_directory": download_dir,
    }
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

    PROXY = "some.proxy.required:80"

    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
        "httpProxy": PROXY,
        "ftpProxy": PROXY,
        "sslProxy": PROXY,
        "noProxy": None,
        "proxyType": "MANUAL",
        "class": "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
        "autodetect": False
    }
    chrome_logpath = os.path.join(basics.dir_main(), "browser.log")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,
                           service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=%s" % chrome_logpath])
```

The whole use case works fine, I am also able to make screenshots which look ok. I cannot post a working example as these cases are password protected.

However, after the download text is clicked the following *empty* file is generated:

```
20171114084223_results.zip.crdownload
```

The actual filename of the download is `results.zip`. I do not see anything strange in the browser logfile.

Is there anything I can try? Is there any other chrome option I can try? Is there any other way to get more debug messages from chrome? Anything...?

Comment: The `.zip.crdownload` is the temporary file created by Chrome when the download starts. This file is renamed once the download is finished. It looks like your script is closing Chrome before the download is finished.

Comment: I am waiting for a long enough time. The download of this file does not take longer than 1 second. I wait 10 seconds. And during the wait time the file's size is always exactly 0 bytes. So it cannot be the script ending too early...

Comment: Maybe it is the case of volume mapping? You cannot see the file on host machine because it is downloaded into docker container.